# Impedance $Z$ for AC source

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, complex-numbers, electrical-engineering

In AC, there are $R$, $C$, & $L$ or $R$, $X_C$, & $X_L$.
$$
X_C = \frac{1}{\omega C}
$$
where $\omega=2\pi f$.

But sometime we're using the $X_C = \frac{1}{j\omega C}$. I understand the $j$ is the imaginary unit and it's current lead voltage in capacitance circuit. But why does the equation sometimes have $j$ and sometimes don't?

Comment: j is always there. Its not needed to describe the capacitive reactance contribution to impedance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the physical meaning of the imaginary component of impedance?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/109736/)

Answer (score 5):

> But why does the equation sometimes have j and sometimes don't?

The reactance $X$ is [the *imaginary part* of the impedance $Z$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_reactance#Impedance) (which is a *complex* number):

$$Z = R + jX$$

and so, $X$ is a *real* number, i.e., there should *never* be an $i$ or a $j$ in the formula for a reactance.

Thus

$$X_L = \omega L,\qquad Z_L = jX_L = j\omega L$$

$$X_C = -\frac{1}{\omega C}, \qquad Z_C = jX_C = -j \frac{1}{\omega C} = \frac{1}{j\omega C}$$

Comment: ah, X when using to find the reactance of the circuit will never have j. It is only when we're talking about Z the impedance that there is the imaginary part reactance X. But there really nothing imaginary about the reactance it was more of a convenience so that we do not accidentally add the resistance load to the reactance load which have different phase angles?