# LCR circuit , impedance, imaginary

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, capacitance, complex-numbers, inductance

What is the physical interpretation in behind impedance of capacitor and inductor? we know that resistance oppose the current in the same direction of voltage.
But how capacitor and impedance oppose the current in perpendicular direction of voltage?
Also discuss why the impedance is a imaginary!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the physical meaning of the imaginary component of impedance?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/109736/)

Comment: Its hard to tell what you understand and what you don't, and asking for a "discussion" makes the question even more broad. Perhaps make this a distinct, clear, question.