# Imaginary Capacitance and Imaginary Inductance interpretation

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, capacitance, complex-numbers, inductance

Today I came across with Complex **Capacitances** and **Inductances** for the first time:
$$L(j\omega)=L_{real}+jL_{imaginary}$$
$$C(j\omega)=C_{real}+jC_{imaginary}$$

So I started looking at their meaning. Let's start with the inductors.

## Inductors:

I found [this article](http://www.femm.info/dmeeker/pdf/chop2.pdf), that states (pages 7 and 8):

---

[image: Inductors - Article Part 1]
[image: Inductors - Article Part 2]

---

After that, I found that this "Power Loss" is associated with "Core Losses", like hysteresis losses, Eddy/Foucault current losses. So, my first question is:

- If $L_{imaginary}<0$, we have $Power\space Loss >0$, so we have a dissipation of energy by the magnetic core of the inductor due to (according to what the article says) eddy currents;
- If $L_{imaginary}=0$, we have $Power\space Loss =0$, so no eddy current and no energy dissipation;

---

But, what if $L_{imaginary}>0$ ? Then we will have $Power\space Loss <0$, i. e., the magnetic core will supply power to the circuit! How is this possible? Or is the value of $L_{imaginary}$ somehow restricted by some equation, so that it cannot assume positive values?

(Another way to state this is considering the inductor impedance:$$Z_L=j\omega L=j\omega\cdot(L_r+jL_i\ )=-\omega L_i+j\omega L_r\ \ $$ The imaginary part of $L$ contributes to the real part of inductor impedance. This contribution is given in the form of a frequency dependent resistance $-\omega L_i$. So, if we have $L_i>0$ then $-\omega L_i<0$, a negative resistance!)

---

## Capacitors:

I found [this article](https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/electrochemistry/75/8/75_8_649/_pdf). It states that (page 2) $C_{imaginary}$ is associated with dielectric loss.

---

[image: Capacitors - Article]

---

Another source states that this dielectric loss can be by Joule's heating effect, hysteresis losses and dielectric absorption. I guess we can model this dielectric loss in a analogous way to the losses in the inductor core:
$$Power\space Loss=-\frac\omega2 C_i v^2$$

Thus, a similar question arises:

- If $C_{imaginary}<0$, we have $Power\space Loss >0$, so we have a dissipation of energy by the dielectric;
- If $C_{imaginary}=0$, we have $Power\space Loss =0$, so no energy dissipation;

---

But, what if $C_{imaginary}>0$ ? Then we will have $Power\space Loss <0$, i. e., the dielectric of the capacitor will supply power to the circuit! Again, how is this possible? Or is the value of $C_{imaginary}$ somehow restricted by some equation, so that it cannot assume positive values?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/109736/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Hi Vinicius ACP, When you edit a closed question, it automatically enters the review queue.

Comment: Can you please inform me how do I narrow the scope of this question even more? I don't know why it remains closed.

Comment: The two questions asked are highly related. I don't think that it's wise to split them into two posts.

Comment: The post seems to be stuck in the review queue for more than 10 days since April 7...We need more reviewers.

Comment: @Qmechanic Is it still in the review queue?

Comment: The timeline log seems to indicate so. Mentioned in the hbar chat room [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/50039128#50039128).

Comment: It [looks like](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) edits only bump "on-hold" questions to the reopen-review queue.  Five days after the question is put on hold, its status changes to "closed." This question wasn't edited until seven days after being put on hold, so it may not have automatically entered the reopen queue.

Comment: @rob So what would you recommend in this situation: delete and repost the question or wait more?

Comment: ${}$Never repost.