Why are complex coordinates outlawed in physics?
In the case of the Kerr metric, for a high enough angular velocity such that on transformation to Boyer-Lindquist coordinates yields complex coordinates for the event horizon, why is it assumed then that the coordinates "disappear"? are complex coordinates completely outlawed in physics?
What about these coordinates means they're designated as non-existent?

What would be the interpretation of 1i meter distance, how would you measure it?

My logic here is, I suppose simply because I can't perceive something shouldn't mean it doesn't exist. I was wondering if we could classify complex coordinates in some plane beyond our standard (x,y,z). My apologies if I am misdirecting myself

Coordinates have units of length and lengths are measurable, if not in practice then in principle. If they can't be measured, how are they physical?

you are not fully missdirected, in some theories there are tachyons with imaginary mass, but I have no idea what that means, I have not looked at them in detail.

That's what I was inferring, for a tachyon to have a real energy it must have an imaginary mass to satisfy E=γmc^2. Could the possibility be considered that we simply do not have the means of interpreting such values?

It used to be common to consider the temporal dimension of spacetime to have coordinates $ict$. Today, complex coordinates are used in 2D conformal field theory. Both of these usages are for mathematical convenience rather than having some deep physical meaning.

I like this question. It reminds me of something I found endlessly confusing as a student. Teachers would stipulate that we can pretend the players in a differential equation were complex, and then we'd take the real part as the solution. The "reason" for this was something ridiculously unmotivated like "real life doesn't have complex values". That statement is insane; if you're going to introduce the complex values at all, you should explain why the real part contains the solution to the original problem. I figured the answer out myself years later.

One problem with coordinates (which aren’t physical) becoming complex is that proper time (which is physical) might then become complex. Since proper time is what a clock measures,  what could it possibly mean for clock time to change from a real number to a complex number?

related: See my answer (where I quote MTW's "Farewell to ict") to https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/327318/minkowskis-complex-euclidean-space-vs-the-real-pseudo-euclidean-version

Simple example: where does the circle $(x-2)^2+(y-2)^2=1$ cross the X or Y axes?

On the related topic of where complex values are physically valid: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/664083/123208 & links therein.

@DanielSank And even worse, there is a perfectly fine way to end up with real values. Just use real initial conditions, then the complex general solution reduces to a real solution without having to ignore part of the solution.

"simply because I can't perceive something shouldn't mean it doesn't exist" Yet that is exactly how physics works. If you cannot percieve (i.e. measure) something, it is worthless as a physical theory, since it cannot make predictions about physical reality.

@DanielSank What was the answer?

@MitchellPorter Not sure if this is always the case, but whenever I saw a problem for which the textbook introduced a complex form of a solution and then took the real part as the final answer, the problem boiled down to a linear equation. And for a linear equation a sum of its solutions is also a solution. Most of the times the imaginary unit doesn't enter the equation, which lets one assert that the complex conjugate of a solution will also be a solution. This lets us add the solution and its complex conjugate, which is equivalent to taking the real part, thus finding a real-valued solution.

Are you certain that complex solutions are "outlawed", i.e. always deemed invalid ? For a while negative values were disregarded in physics till mechanics showed how they might be useful in showing the direction of forces/accelerations/velocities/displacements. Feynman applied interpretation to negative solutions in electrodynamics. Who can truly say that "imaginary" solutions have no relevance ever to a phenomenon ?

Complex Numbers are key to the "complex valued probability" of quantum mechanics. Those are not just two reals mixed into a single value for convenience as do in electronics. Layman intro here: PHYS771 Lecture 9: Quantum - Scott Aaronson. They are why Quantum Computers are interesting and "more powerful" than classical computers, at least for some problems. The mystery of the why they decay into boring real-valued probablities (basically by copying the state heavily, aka "observing") is still not fully elucidated I think.

Interesting question, my +1. However, personally I'd refrain from using the word "outlawed", as there's no "physics police" to arrest you if you use complex numbers. Maybe the word unphysical is better within the context of the question?

@DanielSank That pseudo-argument that "real life doesn't have complex values" is a peculiar one, because it suggests that real numbers DO occur in real life. Irrational numbers like $\sqrt{2}$ and $\pi$ are every bit the abstract figments that imaginary numbers are.

@DavidH that's a very interesting point, one that I hadn't linked to this topic before. Someone had stated earlier that complex numbers may not be used to describe unobservable quantities because that is not the role of physics, physics describes the observable reality. Do you believe that to be the case, or do you believe complex numbers may represent some currently immeasurable concept?

I don't think of complex values as outlawed; on the contrary, they are welcome on condition they add s/th to just plain old 2-dim vectors. Typically, this added value comes from there being a point in multiplying by complex values and/or in changing $+i$ to $-i$. If you routinely handle pairs of values expressed in the same unit, one of which is a scalar and the other a scalar density, you might consider making i the unit density and its sign the handedness of your referentials.


are complex coordinates completely outlawed in physics?

Complex coordinates are “outlawed” specifically in general relativity, which is the relevant physics for your question.
The mathematical framework of general relativity is based on pseudo-Riemannian manifolds. These are defined as structures that are locally isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$. So they cannot be complex by definition of the framework itself.
Complex coordinates can be used in other scenarios. And they were considered in the early days of special relativity. However, the pseudo-Riemannian approach can represent the early complex coordinate metric of special relativity as well as many other metrics that the complex one cannot. So there was no advantage to that approach over the current one.
Of course, it would be possible to relax the requirement and/or consider manifolds locally isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}^n$ and see where the math leads. But just because the modified math would allow it doesn’t mean that it will describe any physical system.

Many physical theories use complex numbers. Quantum mechanics is the obvious example, but even everyday theories like circuit theory use complex numbers, and then we have the more esoteric theories like twistor theory where the space in which it is formulated has three complex dimensions.
So there is nothing wrong with a theory using properties that are complex, but at the end of the day a theory has to predict observable quantities and millennia of experiments by physicists suggests that observable quantities are always real numbers.
In GR the observable quantities are generally Lorentz scalars like the proper time/length, and experiment suggests these have to be real. The problem with naively using a complex dimension is that it allows the proper time to be complex and this contradicts experiment.
Quantum mechanics gets away with it because the wave function is not an observable and the observable quantities are always real because of the way the theory is constructed. Circuit theory gets away with it because it doesn't actually use complex numbers - the complex number is just a way of encoding magnitude and phase into a single quantity. I have no idea how twistor theory gets away with it but apparently it does!

"and millennia of experiments by physicists suggests that observable quantities are always real numbers" - Are they always real numbers, as opposed to merely the real component of a complex quantity whose imaginary component exists but is impossible to observe?

"observable quantities are always real numbers" is that really true? What if I measure the index of refraction of something that absorbs light (its complex)? What if I measure the impedance of a capacitor? There's really nothing wrong with having some measurable quantity that's modelled as a complex number. I mean let's be really silly and measure the "complex position" of an object on a 2d grid, and define the "complex position" as $x+iy$. I really don't think this fundamental rule you propose is a real thing - that all complex parameters of a model are unmeasurable.

is the refraction index an observable?

The refractive index is not really a complex number. It's just a convenient way of combining the refraction and the absorption into a single quantity where the real part describes the refraction and the imaginary part describes the absorption. So when we measure a "complex" refractive index we are really measuring two real physical properties.

The same applies to a "complex" impedance. We are really measuring a real V/I ratio and a real phase shift. It is just convenient to combine them into a single complex number.

Scoot Aaronson: Why did God go with the complex numbers and not the real numbers?: Years ago, at Berkeley, I was hanging out with some math grad students and I asked them that exact question. The mathematicians just snickered. "Give us a break -- the complex numbers are algebraically closed!" To them it wasn't a mystery at all. But to me ... why should Nature run on something that we invented for our convenience?

Speculatively going further The Peculiar Math That Could Underlie the Laws of Nature: New findings are fueling an old suspicion that fundamental particles and forces spring from strange eight-part numbers called “octonions.” ... I don't know what happened to that research angle. (Also, octonions are not 'strange' they are just 'internally consistent' like any mathematical structure)

Complex numbers are used in describing electromagnetic radiation to represent the interaction between the electrical field and magnetic fields as they propagate over time.
All we ask of math in physics generally is that it accurately model the universe. The fact that calling one of these axes imaginary makes the math work does not mean it is imaginary in the colloquial sense, it just means that the square root of -1 happens to be a more useful value than was expected when it was named.

It is probably true that a quantity becoming complex doesn't always or necessarily imply something unphysical. But it does not seem worth the space to give further justification, in most cases.
It could be that two different quantities become complex, but only their product is physically measurable. For example, Taylor & Wheeler make a local Lorentz boost from a static frame to a falling "raindrop" frame in Schwarzschild spacetime (2000, Exploring black holes, §B4, box titled "Metric for the Rain Frame"). However, inside the horizon, this so-called boost is actually superluminal, so the Lorentz factor $\gamma$ becomes complex. Yet, the terms combine so everything turns out real in the end. As I recall there is something similar in Misner, Thorne & Wheeler. Admittedly, the derivation could probably be fixed to avoid complex numbers, so this may not be the best example.
The Newman-Penrose formalism for general relativity uses complex vectors.
Electromagnetism is conveniently formulated using complex vectors. However this is only one of many ways to formulate EM.
An unconventional view is offered by "geometric algebra", which is essentially another name for Clifford algebra. This community looks for physical or geometric interpretations to replace complex numbers. For example, you can define the square of a plane (i.e. a plane multiplied by itself). In some cases, the result is -1. But this avoids scalars $\mathbb C$. Instead, complex numbers are associated with rotation within a plane.
